# Prevent users from entering a date

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have a range of cells that need to be in accounting format. The problem I have is that when users try to enter a date, it changes the cell's format to date and messes up calculations. I want a message box error to pop up and clear invalid data when a user trys to enter in a date.

I already have data validation set up to decimal, but when I try testing it by entering a date (1/2, 1/2/11, or 1-2-11) excel changes the cell's number format to fraction or date and the validation error event does not occur.

Alternatively, is there a way from me to lock the number format for a range of cells so that excel will stop converting the cell's format based on user input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put this code in the VBA module for the worksheet. It shows the message, clears the value and sets the format back to Accounting:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim AccountingRange As Excel.Range
Dim cell As Excel.Range

Set AccountingRange = Me.Range("B2:B20")
If Intersect(Target, AccountingRange) Is Nothing Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Application.EnableEvents = False
For Each cell In Intersect(Target, AccountingRange)
    If IsDate(cell.Text) Then
        With cell
            MsgBox "You entered a date in " & .Address & "." & vbCrLf & "Please don't do that!"
            cell.ClearContents
            .NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
        End With
    End If
Next cell
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for. I'm having a bit of a problem when testing this though. When I type numbers such as 1, 1.1, 1.12 the macro work perfectly for about half of the time. But other times it tells me I entered in a date when I entered a decimal number.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the data validation tool in Excel

[image: Select the validation]

Using this you can force the user to enter a certain type of data in a cell

Comment: I already have data validation set up to decimal, but when I try testing it by entering a date (1/2, 1/2/11, or 1-2-11) excel changes the cell's number format to fraction or date and the validation error does not occur.